# How do I return the TaskStatus when making a synchronous call asynchronous?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have a old data access library that I need to use in my ASP.NET MVC application but I'm having trouble bringing it into the MVC world where many server-side operations are expected to be asynchronous. My data access library looks a like this:

```
public class MyOldDAL
{
    public TaskResult CreateUser(string userName)
    {
        try
        {
            // Do user creation
            return new TaskResult { Success = true, Message = "success" };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new TaskResult { Success = false, Message = ex.Message };
        }
    }
}
```

And is called by my MVC application like this:

```
public class MyUserStore : IUserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    private readonly MyOldDAL _dal = new MyOldDAL();
    public async Task CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => _dal.CreateUser(user.UserName));
    }
}
```

This is fine until the method in `Task.Run()` fails for some reason. I'd like to be able to return `TaskStatus.Faulted` if `TaskResult.Success` is false but I can't find an example online on how to do it properly - all my Google searches turn up is how to use `Task<T>` which the `IUserStore` interface doesn't permit.

For the record, much as I'd like to I can't change `MyOldDAL` - it's targeting .NET 3.5 so no `async` or `await` there!

Comment: why don't you throw an exception if `Success` is `false`?

Comment: I've just tried that - it works but it doesn't seem like a particularly elegant way of doing it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal way to report errors from tasks is via exceptions, so you'll just need to do that transformation yourself:

```
public class MyUserStore : IUserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
  private readonly MyOldDAL _dal = new MyOldDAL();
  public Task CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
  {
    var result = _dal.CreateUser(user.UserName);
    if (result.Success)
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    return Task.FromException(new InvalidOperationException(result.Message));
  }
}
```

Note that `Task.Run` should *not* be used on ASP.NET.

Comment: Great, thanks for clarifying about exceptions. I didn't know about `Task.CompletedTask` etc. so I'll switch over to using that. Is there a technical reason why `Task.Run` isn't used in ASP.NET or is it just convention?

Comment: @Mourndark: The main reason is that `Task.Run` on ASP.NET is unnecessarily inefficient. It also (temporarily) steps "outside" the request context, so e.g., if `MyOldDAL.CreateUser` was depending on the request's user for part of its processing (like permissions checks), it would fail.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** As Stephen Cleary noticed in his answer, `Task.Run` should *not* be used on ASP.NET.

**Original answer (before comments):**
Your `CreateAsync` method should normally be like this:

```
public async Task<TaskResult> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => _dal.CreateUser(user.UserName));
}
```

But if you can't return `Task<TaskResult>` from `CreateAsync` method... well, than you can't obtain `TaskResult` from `CreateAsync` by definition. In that case you can store result locally:

```
private TaskResult taskResult;

public async Task CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
    var result = await Task.Run(() => _dal.CreateUser(user.UserName));
    this.taskResult = result;
    // process taskResult wherether you need
}
```

Or raise event with `TaskResult` payload, allowing client of `MyUserStore` to subscribe to this event:

```
public event EventHandler<TaskResult> TaskCompleted;

public async Task CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
    var result = await Task.Run(() => _dal.CreateUser(user.UserName));
    this.OnTaskCompleted(result);
}

private void OnTaskCompleted(TaskResult result)
{
    this.TaskCompleted?.Invoke(this, result);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear that I'm replacing part of ASP.NET Identity and I didn't write the code that calls `CreateAsync`. I'm not bothered if `MyUserStore` knows about the failure or not, but whatever is calling `CreateAsync` absolutely has to know whether the operation succeeded or not.

Comment: Do you mean that you can't change `MyUserStore` class, which means that you can't change return type and can't add event to it? In that case, can you pass any parameters to `MyUserStore`? And can you edit `MyOldDAL` class?

Comment: Not quite, I can't change the method signature for `CreateAsync` so I can't change the return type to `Task<T>` or pass in extra parameters. The rest of `MyUserStore` has more flexibility.

Comment: Are you using single instance of `MyUserStore`, or you can use several instances and must distinguish between them?

Comment: With `async Task CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)` signature you can't obtain `TaskResult`, it is just impossible because it returns void. Can you modify `ApplicationUser` class?